# PHPExcel Switch from Row to Column

Tags: php, charts, phpexcel

I've already generate Chart Bar using PHPExcel by load or reading php file. I've successful write data into it, but the problem is to change chart bar data plot from rows to columns. Here the excel file.

[Excel File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgekD.png) or [EF1](http://idraya.com/stackoverflow/excel.png)

Here the code to generate chart.

```php
<?php
$objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();

$dataSeriesLabels = array(  new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('String', 'Responden!$C$8', NULL, 1),  // Jan
                            new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('String', 'Responden!$D$8', NULL, 1),  // Feb
                            new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('String', 'Responden!$E$8', NULL, 1),  // Mar
                            new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('String', 'Responden!$F$8', NULL, 1),  // Apr
                            new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('String', 'Responden!$G$8', NULL, 1),  // Mei
                            new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('String', 'Responden!$H$8', NULL, 1),  // Jun
                            new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('String', 'Responden!$I$8', NULL, 1),  // Jul
                            new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('String', 'Responden!$J$8', NULL, 1),  // Aug
                            new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('String', 'Responden!$K$8', NULL, 1),  // Sep
                            new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('String', 'Responden!$L$8', NULL, 1),  // Okt
                            new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('String', 'Responden!$M$8', NULL, 1),  // Nov
                            new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('String', 'Responden!$N$8', NULL, 1)   // Des
                        );

$xAxisTickValues = array( new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('String', 'Responden!$B$9:$B$16', NULL, 8) // Questions
                        );

$dataSeriesValues = array(  new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('Number', 'Responden!$C$9:$C$16', NULL, 8),
                            new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('Number', 'Responden!$D$9:$D$16', NULL, 8),
                            new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('Number', 'Responden!$E$9:$E$16', NULL, 8),
                            new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('Number', 'Responden!$F$9:$F$16', NULL, 8),
                            new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('Number', 'Responden!$G$9:$G$16', NULL, 8),
                            new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('Number', 'Responden!$H$9:$H$16', NULL, 8),
                            new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('Number', 'Responden!$I$9:$I$16', NULL, 8),
                            new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('Number', 'Responden!$J$9:$J$16', NULL, 8),
                            new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('Number', 'Responden!$K$9:$K$16', NULL, 8),
                            new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('Number', 'Responden!$L$9:$L$16', NULL, 8),
                            new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('Number', 'Responden!$M$9:$M$16', NULL, 8),
                            new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('Number', 'Responden!$N$9:$N$16', NULL, 8)
                        );

$series = new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries(
                PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries::TYPE_BARCHART,       // plotType
                PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries::GROUPING_CLUSTERED,  // plotGrouping
                range(0, count($dataSeriesValues)-1),           // plotOrder //array(0,1)
                $dataSeriesLabels,                              // plotLabel
                $xAxisTickValues,                               // plotCategory
                $dataSeriesValues                               // plotValues
            );

$series->setPlotDirection(PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries::DIRECTION_COL);


$plotArea = new PHPExcel_Chart_PlotArea($layout, array($series));
$legend = new PHPExcel_Chart_Legend(PHPExcel_Chart_Legend::POSITION_BOTTOM, NULL, false);
$title = new PHPExcel_Chart_Title('GRAFIK TINGKAT KEPENTINGAN DAN KEPUASAN');
$xAxisLabel = NULL; //PHPExcel_Chart_Title('NilaiX');
$yAxisLabel = NULL; //new PHPExcel_Chart_Title('NilaiY');

//  Create the chart
$chart = new PHPExcel_Chart(
                'chart_measurement',    // name
                $title,                 // title
                $legend,                // legend
                $plotArea,              // plotArea
                true,                   // plotVisibleOnly
                0,                      // displayBlanksAs
                $xAxisLabel,            // xAxisLabel
                $yAxisLabel             // yAxisLabel
            );

$chart->setTopLeftPosition('F7');
$chart->setBottomRightPosition('AB20');
$objWorksheet->addChart($chart);
?>
```

[Here the result of chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0uYY.png) or [R1](http://idraya.com/stackoverflow/result1.png)

But i want to change the chart to be like this

[the result should be looks like here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZqPCv.png) or [R2](http://idraya.com/stackoverflow/result2.png)

in my perception i call it to switch the data plot from rows to columns. Thanks a lot before for your contribution.